# How can you check if the directory exists using a while loop in bash?

Tags: bash

How can you check if the directory exists using a while loop in bash?
In general, words what I want is while true if directory exists to do something

Comment: Sounds like you've got the gist. Have you looked at some basic bash syntax guides to see if you can turn your pseudocode into bash?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following construct to check if a folder (with name $dirname) exists:

```
[ -d $dirname ]
```

This will exit successfully if the folder exists, allowing for the following code:

```
[-d $dirname ] && echo "exists" || echo "does not exist"
```

or

```
if [ -d $dirname ]; then
    echo "exists"
fi
```